# HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url via Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365api

I tried this sample code for my org (for which my AD admin gave full access in SharePoint :

```
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = "https://myname.sharepoint.com"
client_id = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxx"

ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret))

folder_path = 'sites/SOF'
root_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(folder_path).expand(["Files"]).get().execute_query()
print("root_folder = ", root_folder)

for file in root_folder.files:
    print(file.name)
```

But I still get

```
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://myname.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='sites%2FSOF')?$expand=Files
```

I even tried `site_url = "https://myname.sharepoint.com/sites/SOF"` but still it returned :

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://myname.sharepoint.com/sites/SOF/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='')?$expand=Files
```

**Update** : entering this in my browser returns the proper XML with all the data :

[https://myname.sharepoint.com/sites/SOF/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='Shared%20Documents')?$expand=Files](https://myname.sharepoint.com/sites/SOF/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl=%27Shared%20Documents%27)?$expand=Files)

So what more permissions do I need from my admin ? My client_id and client_secret are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Application**:

[image]

Now when I tried the code, I got the **same error** as below:

[image]

The **`403 error`** usually occurs if the application doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the action.

**To resolve the error,** make sure to set up an app-only principal with tenant permissions like below:

- If you are **Tenant Admin**, then use this `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`
- If you have **Global Admin** role, then use this `https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`

I used **`https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`** to grant permissions:

*And here enter the ClientID, domain and redirect URL of the application.*

For **App's permission,** paste the below XML and create:

```xml
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

[image]

Now click on **`Trust it`** to grant the permissions:

[image]

I uploaded **samples files** in the SharePoint site:

[image]

Now, after granting the permissions **I am able to print the files successfully** like below:

```py
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testruk"
client_id = "ClientID"
client_secret = "ClientSecret"

ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret))

folder_path = 'doc1/folder1'
root_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(folder_path).expand(["Files"]).get().execute_query()
print("root_folder = ", root_folder)

for file in root_folder.files:
    print(file.name)
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

Comment: Thank You Very Much - I couldn't get this link https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx from google - this step was missed.