# Sharepoint Rest API office365 library 403 Client Error

Tags: python, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to access a Sharepoint folder and retrieve the files within.

With the following code:

```
# Import libraries
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential

# Config for Sharepoint (to be stored in env later)
SP_CLIENT_ID = xxx
SP_CLIENT_SECRET = xxx
SP_URL = 'https://<organization_url>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>'
relative_folder_url = '/Shared%20Documents/<subfolder>'

# App-based authentication with access credentials
context = ClientContext(SP_URL).with_credentials(ClientCredential(SP_CLIENT_ID, SP_CLIENT_SECRET))
folder = context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(relative_folder_url)
context.load(folder)
context.execute_query()

# Processes each Sharepoint file in folder
for file in folder.files:
    print(f'Processing file: {file.properties["Name"]}')
```

However, it throws an error

```
office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException', 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))', "403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-id>/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='%2Fsites%2F<site-name>%2FDocuments%2FGeneral%2F<subfolder>')")` stemming from `context.execute_query()

with the specific names replaced by <xxx>.
```

I am able to retrieve files using `Graph API` on `Postman`, using the same `SP_CLIENT_ID` and `SP_CLIENT_SECRET`. It is done by generating a token using the `client ID` and `secret`, then passing token in Graph GET API calls.

It appears the app-based authentication is fine as the error is `403`.

How can it be fixed such that files can be programmatically seen (and ultimately downloaded) through Sharepoint Rest API on Python?

Edit:
The error is likely coming from the lack of permission granted for Sharepoint Rest API on the Azure app I am using to authenticate with Sharepoint.
Now I am thinking if I should continue using `office365` or simply use some pure API approach like `requests` library in Python to programmatically download Sharepoint files.

Comment: Could you include what `API permissions` you granted in the application?

Comment: @Sridevi There is one "Sites.Selected" permission name for Type "Application", it requires admin consent. The rest are "Delegation" types not requiring admin consent. They are all Microsoft Graph permissions. It may be why the Sharepoint Rest API cannot access, as there are no non-Graph permissions granted.

Comment: @Sridevi For Sharepoint permission no. For Graph permission yes. The error is very likely to come from the lack of SP permission. I am debating whether to completely stop using office365 and simply do Python `requests` for Graph to carry out Sharepoint file downloading programmatically.

Comment: Check whether you created the app registration and added permissions to it as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs#setting-up-an-app-only-principal-with-tenant-permissions). To call SharePoint using office365 via client credentials flow, you need to set up app-only principal with required permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one SharePoint site named **sritestsite10** having few files in following path:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** as below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I ran below URL with **Global Administrator** account and added app-only principal with tenant permissions like this:

```
https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
```

You can find your Azure AD application by entering **`AppId`** and use below xml for adding permissions:

```xml
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

[image]

Make sure to click on **Trust it** option to grant the permissions:

[image]

When I ran the code again by adding **`.expand(["Files"])`** to folder variable, I got the **response** successfully as below:

```py
# Import libraries
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential

# Config for Sharepoint (to be stored in env later)
SP_CLIENT_ID = xxx
SP_CLIENT_SECRET = xxx
SP_URL = 'https://<organization_url>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>'
relative_folder_url = '/Shared%20Documents/<subfolder>'

# App-based authentication with access credentials
context = ClientContext(SP_URL).with_credentials(ClientCredential(SP_CLIENT_ID, SP_CLIENT_SECRET))
folder = context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(relative_folder_url).expand(["Files"])
context.load(folder)
context.execute_query()

# Processes each Sharepoint file in folder
for file in folder.files:
    print(f'Processing file: {file.properties["Name"]}')
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure - HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url via Office365-REST-Python-Client - Stack Overflow by **Rukmini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759790/httperror-403-client-error-forbidden-for-url-via-office365-rest-python-client)